# Using the latest JRE instead of older a Java versions, am I guaranteed it will work?

Tags: java

Lets say I have a Java project that is coded with Java 1.5 and I'm using a later version of Java but set target to 1.5.

If the code compiles and tests OK with the later Java, am I then guaranteed that it will work the same on an actual Java 1.5 runtime?

Or will I need to install one version of all JRE that I depend on to be sure?

What happens with bugs in the JRE? If there is a bug in 1.5, that is fixed in 1.6. If I use Java 1.6 with target set to 1.5, will that bug affect me?

In a realistic scenario, is this a concern that I need to have at all?

Comment: I ran into the following problem: java7 added new methods to an already existing interface. Even after setting it to java6 compliance, the compiler told me I had to implement the missing methods (annotating it with `@Override`). After doing so, java6 told me it didn't know the new overwritten methods. But maybe it was an eclipse-only problem...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you set target **and source** to 1.5, you only need to be worried in three main cases I can think of:

- You're using internal `com.sun` classes, which may have changed or disappeared (or relying on some other internal behaviour somehow.)
- You're relying on buggy behaviour which was fixed in a later version.
- You run into a backwards incompatible change (rare but it has been known to happen.)

  > What happens with bugs in the JRE? If there is a bug in 1.5, that is fixed in 1.6. If I use Java 1.6 with target set to 1.5, will that bug affect me?

If the bug is in the libraries, then no it won't affect you. Target only really stipulates the version of the bytecode you compile against, you'll still be using the updated libraries. As said earlier, note however this could potentially cause issues if you rely on this buggy behaviour.

If there is a deliberate backwards incompatible change, then all cases I've seen of this present themselves as compile time errors rather than runtime errors, so they'll be trivial to spot (and usually pretty easy to fix as well.)

I'd still advocate testing on the new version of the JVM before you release, but in practice it's not *usually* a problem, in my experience anyway.

Answer (score 5):

All new JRE implementations are made in the way of maintaining compatibility, so the answer is **yes**. 
However, I suggest that you **test your app** as there might be problems very specific to your project.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up your question:
Is JRE backward compatible, and is JDK forward compatible?

The short answer is **yes**.

**Explanation:**
JDK's are not backward compatible. i.e
JDK5 code can't run on JVM4, or JDK6 on JVM5.

However JRE is made backward compatible, because often the organizations *write once, execute many times*

**Why:**
As the JRE's become more and more sophisticated, with more intelligent Heap management, Garbage collection, thread handling etc, customers are tempted to move to newer version of JVM.

**Bugs**
Real bugs present in JVM will stop behaving that way, if you use later version JVM with earlier 'target'. This is because `target=prev_version` doesn't really invoke altogether previous JVM.
It only picks up *delta* and treats the code differently. However if it was a feature introduced intentionally in new JVM (say 6), switching to target=1.5 will actually fallback to beahvior for 1.5

Hope that clarifies your doubt to certain extent.